Show UIActivityViewController from View , how to set sourceView
I'm trying to share a link from my app. It seems like we should use UIActivityViewController to do this.
This is how I'm trying to do it:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       ...
       Button(action: { shareLink() } .. )
    }

    func shareLink() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(
            activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

When I run on a connected device, I get a crash:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x1026c8700>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'

I'm not sure how to set sourceView here, most examples I've been finding are using deprecated approaches, I'm not sure about pursuing those or what the current way to do this is.
Thanks

Cannot reproduce, iPhone 15 iOS 17.5.1

Yeah it doesn't crash on a simulator, but crashes on a real iPad running 18.0.1

My current way to show a UIActivityViewController is create a SwiftUI View conform to UIViewControllerRepresentable to wrap UIActivityViewController, then we can use present modifer to present that view.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showShare: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            showShare = true
        }) {
            Text("Share")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showShare) {
            WrapUIActivityViewController(url: URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!)
        }
    }
}


struct WrapUIActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIActivityViewController {
        UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: Context) {
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIActivityViewController
}

